# Query time out error while handling multiple queries in a single form

Tags: vb.net

I am developing an inquiry screen having totally 13 tabs consists of 13 grids. When the entire process running on the given selection criteria on the button click it taking too much time to execute and giving time out error.  I am using visual studio 2005 and all server 2008 R2.  While individual running the SQL' S they are working fine. Please suggest me the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the timeout of your `Command` object or optimize your sql query to take less time.

Comment: Yeah I already did it. Is there any way that while execution of one query comes back and fetch it back to grid..